# Generalized Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, gauge-integral

Is there any usage of studying the Henstock-Kurzweil
integral as such ?

It doesn't seem to be as popular a method of integration as the Lebesgue integral or even the Riemann-Stieltjes Integral,although all functions that are Riemann and Lebesgue integrable are also Henstock-Kurzweil integrable.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The path integral approach needs a notion of integration not relying on absolute integrability as is the Lebesgue integral. See [Feynman's Path Integral and Henstock's Non-Absolute Integration](http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jaa/jaa06/jaa06001.pdf) with an original quote by Feynman himself.